# Correct delimiter expression for csv next line in Spring Cloud Dataflow Filesplitter Processor

Tags: csv, spring-cloud-stream, spring-el, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-properties

I'm using the Spring Cloud Dataflow server and I am polling csv files with the Time source and the http client processor. 
Now I want to split the polled csv file and pipeline single line-by-line messages. Since the HttpClientProcessor polls entire files only, I'm using a FileSplitter processor in order to archieve that. But I'm stuck on that. The relevant FileSplitter options are `delimiters` and `expression`.

The `delimiters` options hint says

> When expression is null, delimiters to use when tokenizing {@link String} payloads.

The `expression` options hint says

> A SpEL expression for splitting payloads.

I've tried lots of possibilities more than just a simple `\n` for both options without success. 
The `expression` option literally always fire the following error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'splitter.expression' to org.springframework.expression.Expression:

Property: splitter.expression
Value: \n
Origin: System Environment Property "SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON"
Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.expression.Expression
```

Approaches on the `delimiters` option lead into a successful start of the applications, but my log-sink is not getting any input. My delimiter options are different from what is recognized as *the real* 'new line'-character in csv.

Does anyone have an idea on what option(s) I have to input for `delimiters` or `expression` in order to split the csv message line-by-line? 
Implementing my own FileSplitter processor app seems to be an overkill but I will do it **if need be**...

Comment: Hi, could you please edit the post and add the versions in use? Perhaps also include the stream definition that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Hi @SabbyAnandan , Ive implemented my own '@Splitter' with a delimiter property. It was basically a 3-liner and I had no problems on passing the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example working syntax with the **expression** argument providing \\n.

> stream create --name name --definition “http --port=9090|splitter
> --expression=payload.split(‘\\n’) |custom|log